# How to pass parameters properly with AJAX get request

Tags: jquery

I am making a AJAX get request this way

```
$(document).on("click", ".topp", function () 
{
 var id_attr_val = $(this).attr("id");
 alert(id_attr_val);
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/oms/toppings',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data : "topping="+id_attr_val+"",
            jsonp: false,
            success: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("WebSerivce unreachable");
            }
        });
});
```

The alert value is being displayed as 59 , but when i observed in the console , its making a call this way

```
http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/oms/toppings?topping=59&_=1402670107061
```

Could you please tell me how can i send 59 , instead of those extra characters ??

Answer (score 3):

To 'remove' the `&_=1402670107061` part you would have to set the following in your `ajax` request:

```
cache: true,
```

And, yes, you can still use `data: {topping: id_attr_val },`.

> **cache** ***(default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')***
>   Type: Boolean
>   If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending **"_={timestamp}"** to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `topping` value in your server script, you will find it is correctly set to 59.

The extra characters you see are a second variable, called `_` being sent with a value of `1402670107061`. You can see this by the `&` character, which is used to separate multiple GET parameters.

As for what this `_` variable is for, it is jQuery's cache busting, to ensure the request always goes to the server not the browser's cache. It defaults to `true` when using `dataType: jsonp`. See [Who Add "_" Single Underscore Query Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687729/who-add-single-underscore-query-parameter) and the **cache** parameter of http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. If you want to get rid of it and allow results to be cached, set `cache: true` on the AJAX options.

Comment: @PreethiJain Updated: **As for what this `_` variable is for, it is likely some kind of cache busting. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687729/who-add-single-underscore-query-parameter)**

Answer (score 1):

Your current code should still work when you go to use the value of toppings as the `&` separates two different parameters.

After looking throught the jquery docs I found that setting `cache:true` in your ajax options will remove the `_` parameter.

Howerver, you should consider if you actually want to allow caching instead of just removing it. I don't know the scope of your project so that's for you to figure out.

Also if you want to reformat your ajax you have two options.

```
url: 'http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/oms/toppings',
```

becomes

```
url: 'http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/oms/toppings?topping=' + id_attr_val,
```

and remove the data memeber

or

```
data : "topping="+id_attr_val+"",
```

becomes

```
data : {topping:id_attr_val},
```