# How to remove “_” Single Underscore Query Parameter when perfoming ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove “_” underscore Query Parameter when using

Example I am using, with not success (no errors) the following code, please note I use  jQuery v1.9.1

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  cache: false
})
```

Comment: How does your example code show the problem? I see no underscore.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687729/who-add-single-underscore-query-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underline are appearing because you set the `cache: false` option, as denoted on [jQuery Documentation for Ajax Settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).