# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 () and mysterius input

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

I have this function

```
function AddComment(id) {
    var input = $("#" + "CommentOnPost" + id).val();
  
    var commentHolder = $("#commentDiv" + id);
    commentHolder.empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Account/AddCommentToPost',
        data: { postId: id, text:input },
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            //irrelevant
        },
    });
}
```

But when debugging it, I can see that is makes the following request:

> `https://localhost:44398/Account/AddCommentToPost?postId=1&text=gd&_=1596616234410`

That extra parameter "_" should not be there and is perhaps causing the problem?

Comment: A 405 means the server has a match for the URL but not the method. Perhaps your server is expecting a POST request instead of GET

Comment: The `_` is added by jQuery as a cache buster and is typically a good idea. It won't be causing the problem. See [Who Add “_” Single Underscore Query Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687729/who-add-single-underscore-query-parameter)

Comment: @Phil yeah, adding type:"POST" solved it. Silly of me to forget that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you applied [`[HttpPost]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httppostattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to an action,  which would identify your action that supports the HTTP POST method only. Your Ajax code snippet would make '**GET**' request, which cause ["405 Method Not Allowed"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) error.

To fix it, as you mentioned, you can try to set `type`  option with 'POST'.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Account/AddCommentToPost',
    type: 'POST',
    //...
```

Or remove `[HttpPost]` attribute from your action method to make it support both GET and POST request(s).