# datatable adding a default query "_" for ajax request in server side processing

Tags: javascript, datatables

```
let draw; //Draw Variable For datatable
const policytable = $("#policyTable").DataTable({ //Initialising PolicyList Table
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    pagingType: "simple_numbers",
    rowId: "_id",
    ajax: {
        url: `SomeURL`,
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: function(d) {
            draw = d.draw;
            let requestBody = { from: d.start, size: d.length, activeStatus: true, sortBy: d.columns[d.order[0].column].name, orderBy: d.order[0].dir };
            if (d.search.value) {
                requestBody.keyword = d.search.value;
            };
            console.log("REQUEST BODY", requestBody);
            return (requestBody);
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
    },
    order: [1, "asc"],
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: 0,
        orderable: false,
        searchable: false,
        width: "3%",
        className: "select-checkbox",
        checkboxes: {
            selectRow: true
        }
    }],
    select: {
        style: "multi",
        selector: "td:first-child"
    },
    columns: [{
            defaultContent: "",
        },
        {
            title: "Name",
            name: "name",
            data: "name"
        },
});
```

[image: Image with query parameters highlighted]
[image: Request Body Console]

Now The problem is that _ query that is being added for whatever reason as can be seen in image.While console for requestBody also does not show that particular parameter.I have also added an image with the console since I can't create a code snippet.I have gone through datatable official docs as well yet I cant find any explanation.I want to know what that "_" is and how can I avoid sending in as request query.

Comment: I don't see the ```_``` result in your pictures. Do you mean ```_proto_```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who Add "\_" Single Underscore Query Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687729/who-add-single-underscore-query-parameter)

Comment: no the image above it.I have highlighted it with blue background in query parameters.And if u look at the request Body there is not no parameter like that

Comment: See also [Option to disable adding the underscore timestamp parameter to script src](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4898) for notes on disabling this _if you really need to_. I have never needed/wanted to.

Comment: Thanks andrew.yes it answers it perfectly.Again Thanks a lot.